# Access Denied when trying to create an item with SharePoint API

Tags: list, rest, publishing-page, api

I am using OAuth to authenticate a client to access SharePoint and create some files. I have the access token and can access endpoints with no issues. However, when it comes to creating items, I am getting Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. My user has full admin rights on the site and I have also attached every single scope at the highest possible level to the access token request.

Any one come across this before. It is really frustrating and costing me valuable time.

```
'AllProfiles.Manage',
                        'Web.Manage',
                        'Site.Manage',
                        'List.Manage',
                        'AllSites.Manage',
                        'Search.QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal',
                        'TermStore.Write',
                        'AllProfiles.Manage',
                        'ProjectResources.Write'
```

Those are the scopes I requested for and I am simply trying to create a new page.